# Plane falls not on collision surface

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I follow through my first Blender lesson and have a problem. Tissue falls as if current point of view is collision surface, not table.

I did set up *Collison* property on table and saucer and also set up tissue as *Cloth* (Silk).
[image: Current POV]

[image: Other POV]

Blend file: https://dropmefiles.com/uP7MZ

Comment: @hinotf Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with cloth is: it works only with a special (i mean big by this) size, so in object mode in your scene press A to select all, press S 10 -> which sizes all up to 10x, play your simulation and you will get this smooth result:

[image]